# Windows keeps asking for MP4 software to use despite VLC Player selection

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player, file-association

I have allocated VLC Player to open .mp4 files from `Settings -> Default Apps -> Choose default apps by file type`, see screenshot labeled **Before**. But when I try to open an mp4 file, it still asked me to select which program I want to use for this file, see screenshot labeled **After**. Why doesn't setting it from `Settings` let it know which program I want to use?

I use Windows 10 Home 22H2 if it helps.

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: What happens if you check "Always use this app to open .mp4 f‌iles" and click OK?

Comment: It opens the file with VLC Player and keeps using it for later.

Answer (score 1):

Because a new application is now available to open those files: "Media Player". This dialog will appear every time a new application is available for a file type.

Once again confirm you will keep using VLC, using the checkbox at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I have encountered many times - the Settings app is
not doing its job correctly.

However, using "Always use this app to open .xxx f‌iles" works for
most file types (xxx). This is why I usually don't bother assigning
file-extensions via the Settings app.

You may signal the bug to Microsoft via the Feedback Hub, but fixing
Microsoft software is not something that you can do yourself (or me).